# How to properly remove `mariadb` from `WAMP`?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, mariadb, wamp

i have installed `wamp` to use `mysql` but it took too much space. In my `C:\wamp64\bin` directory i found the following folders

- apache
- mariadb
- mysql
- php

So i think i installed `mariadb` along with `mysql`. As far i know mariadb is different database and has nothing to do with mysql right? If so how can i remove maridb properly?(so that no unnecessary files are left and wamp runs properly)? Please help im a beginer

Comment: MariaDB is a fork of MySQL. However, know that they are quickly getting divergent, so what works for one might not for the other, depending upon the versions.